# How to run a condition on each element in a Pandas Series and split into two rows

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop

I have a Pandas dataset containing business information.

Columns include: 'Business Name' and 'Street Address'

I am trying to categorize my dataset by street address, however, some of these addresses contain suite numbers.

For example, the street address could be:

```
'111 New Montgomery St Suite 101'
'222 Second Ave'
'111 New Montgomery St'
```

I am trying to separate the suite numbers into a separate column. So I created a new column called 'Suite' and filled it's default value to `None`

Next, I split the string into a list.

```
['111', 'New', 'Montgomery', 'St', 'Suite', '101']
```

Then, I identify the index of the street suffix (St, Ave, Dr, etc). In this case, the index would be `3`.

Next, I want to divide the list into two lists, using the index of the suffix as a divider:
`['111', 'New', 'Montgomery', 'St']` and `['Suite', '101']`

I am having trouble assigning:

`['111', 'New', 'Montgomery', 'St']` to the 'Street Address' column

and

`['Suite', '101']` to 'Suite' column

Note: The location of the street suffix varies, which doesn't allow me to use the replace function (to my knowledge). Instead, I am currently using iterrows.

Thank you!

Comment: You need to combine the list of strings into single string and then append into pd dataframe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like the kind of job for reg ex:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Address': ['111 New Montgomery St Suite 101', '222 Second Ave', '111 New Montgomery St']
})

address = df['Address'].str.extract(r'(.+?)($| Suite \d+)', expand=True)
address.columns = ['StreetAddress', 'Suite']
address['Suite'] = address['Suite'].str.strip()

df.join(address)
```

Result:

```
                           Address          StreetAddress       Suite
0  111 New Montgomery St Suite 101  111 New Montgomery St   Suite 101
1                   222 Second Ave         222 Second Ave            
2            111 New Montgomery St  111 New Montgomery St
```

Having said that, real address cleaning is really complex. The first address could have been written as `Ste. 101, 111 New Montgomery St` or `#101, 111 New Montgomery St`. There are web services that help you do so.

Comment: Do you have any recommendations on a address cleaning web service? and thank you for the recommendation on reg ex!